# Office 2007 on a Windows 2003 x64 Terminal Server Installs Slowly

Tags: terminal-server, microsoft-office-2007

We have a Windows 2003 x64 Terminal Server with Office 2003. I'm trying to install Office 2007 Pro. I've set Permission Compatibility to Full Security so the installation starts properly. NOD32 is disabled after rebooting the server. No users are on the system.

But still, 12 hours later the installation isn't half done. No errors in the app log -- only progress of the different Office products that have been installed.

The first terminal server I installed Office 2007 on is configured in a similar way, and that upgrade happened in less than 30 minutes.

Comment: The subsequent windows updates for Office 2007 only are updating at about 45 minutes per update.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not with Office or Windows, but an issue with terminal servers and HP printer drivers and monitors. In this case, I used Autoruns to see what was starting. After disabling HP P1006 Language Monitor, HP1100LM, HP2030Lm, HPPMOPJL, and hpz3l4a, it was possible to uninstall and upgrade apps.

References:

- http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c01682861&dimid=1002759220&dicid=alr_mar09&jumpid=em_alerts/us/mar09/all/xbu/emailsubid/mrm/mcc/loc/rbu_category/alerts
- http://forums13.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?admit=109447627+1286236900909+28353475&threadId=1259636-

-